# Problem with spring boot graphql. Request /graphql results with 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I'm trying to run simplest graphql example. I created application with spring initializer and only added graphql dependencies. My `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.3.1'
    compile 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.3.1'
    compile 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:voyager-spring-boot-starter:5.3.1'
}
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I run the project and hit the endpoint `/graphql` it returns `404`. What is missing in my configuration?

Comment: Did you check the port you're requesting on? And does Spring log anything when receiving the request?

Comment: Yes, I checked the port. 404 means that server received the request.

Comment: That's true, my bad. And this graphql package you have in your dependencies is supposed to expose the endpoint `/graphql` automatically? I see it's in your deps, but there's no further config regarding graphql api.

Comment: Docs are quite messy, cant find any minimal working example here https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot. I must have been missed sth important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The docs (https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot#enable-graphql-servlet) say:

> The servlet becomes accessible at /graphql if graphql-spring-boot-starter added as a dependency to a boot application and a GraphQLSchema bean is present in the application.

...and the minimum example it links to looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationBootConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationBootConfiguration.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    GraphQLSchema schema() {
        return GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
            .query(GraphQLObjectType.newObject()
                .name("query")
                .field(field -> field
                    .name("test")
                    .type(Scalars.GraphQLString)
                    .dataFetcher(environment -> "response")
                )
                .build())
            .build();
    }
}
```

So you're missing a Graphql schema to be used. It says if there is one, the API endpoint will be exposed automatically.
Good luck!

Comment: does not work, throws another error on startup saying that you need a bean of type GraphQL

Answer (score 3):

I had a equal problem using graphiql and Swagger
The page graphiql got me erros 404 on browser console. The problem was that cannot get the js library from vendor resource.

On `class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport`

I did:

```
@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
//This is for graphiql works
registry.addResourceHandler("/vendor/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/vendor/");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following steps resolved the issue:

1. Create a directory named src/main/resources/graphql.
2. Within this directory, add a new file named anyname.graphqls.
3. Add the following schema to the file:

```
type Query { 
    test: String 
}
```

It was challenging to find a solution, as the absence of the directory and file didn't trigger any errors. Instead, accessing /graphql resulted in a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a very simple GraphQL application that I had made based on an article, when I tested the `http://localhost:8989/graphql` with Postman I got `404 NOT_FOUND` error, in my case the problem was that I was testing the API with a REST POST request call in the Postman, you need to create a new GraphQL request by clicking on `New` button in Postman and then if your application has been launched, automatically accessible API's is displayed, see the below screenshot:
[image]